# Error object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing even CascadeType is ALL

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I'm trying to save an object but i get theese errors:

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : com.example.magra.erp.models.entity.ventas.OrdenVenta.contacto -> com.example.magra.erp.models.entity.maestro.ClienteContacto

java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : com.example.magra.erp.models.entity.ventas.OrdenVenta.cliente -> com.example.magra.erp.models.entity.maestro.Cliente
```

The three Entities in question are here:

**Orden Venta**

```
    @Entity
@Table(name="ven_orden_venta")
public class OrdenVenta implements Serializable {
    ...

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler, contactos"}, allowSetters = false)
    private Cliente cliente;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"}, allowSetters = false)
    private ClienteContacto contacto;
   
    ...
 
    //getters and setters
}
```

**Cliente**

```
    @Entity
@Table(name="mae_cliente")
public class Cliente implements Serializable {

    ...
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({ "hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler" })
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "cliente_id")
    private List<ClienteContacto> contactos;
    ...
 
    //getters and setters
}
```

**ClienteContacto**

```
    @Entity
@Table(name="mae_cliente_contacto")
public class ClienteContacto implements Serializable {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    
    @Column(length=200)
    private String nombres;
    
    @Column(length=150)
    private String apellidoPaterno;
    
    @Column(length=150)
    private String apellidoMaterno;
    
    @Column(length=15)
    private String telefono;
    
    @Column(length=15)
    private String celular;
    
    @Column(length=250)
    private String correo;

    private Integer idUsuarioCrea;
    
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date fechaCrea;

    private Integer idUsuarioModifica;
    
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date fechaModifica;
 
    //getters and setters
}
```

I don't know what is my error. Thanks in advance.

Searching a solution, i found that using CascadeType.ALL solve this error. But that's not my case.

I used CascadeType.ALL and droped the table for create it again, but that not solve the error.

Comment: Cascade all would work except for Spring's save implementation. Its save will check if the object passed in is new - if it is, it uses persist. Since your referenced entities are existing, the persist operation cascaded over them is required to cause an exception - you cannot call persist on an existing, detached entity instance. You would need to call merge which will look at the entity and decide if it is new or existing and handle it appropriately. Spring behavior in save defeats JPA cascade settings unfortunately - you need to implement it yourself or use an update method.

Answer (score 0):

Saving Cliente and ClienteContacto entity first and asign the objects created to OrdenVenta object, solve the problem

```
@PostMapping("/orden-venta/create")
public ResponseEntity<?> create(@RequestBody OrdenVenta ordenVenta){
    Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<>();
    
    try {
        Cliente cliente = clienteService.save(ordenVenta.getCliente());
        ordenVenta.setCliente(cliente);
        ClienteContacto contacto = contactoService.findByCorreo(ordenVenta.getContacto().getCorreo());
        ordenVenta.setContacto(contacto);
        ordenVentaService.save(ordenVenta);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        response.put("ind", 0);
        return new ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>(response, HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
    }

    response.put("ind", 1);
    return new ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```